# Retrofit Gson - json deserlization

Tags: gson, retrofit

My webservice returns json in the following format

```
{"Result":"{\"GetUserList\":[{\"UserName\":\"Ganesh\",\"password\":\"pass\"},{\"UserName\":\"Mayur\",\"password\":\"pass123\"},{\"UserName\":\"Ramesh\",\"password\":\"pass345\"}]}"}
```

gson is unable to deseralize it into the POJO , is their any simple way i can deseralize without writing custom deseralizer

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY)
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ")
            .create();

    final RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://10.0.2.2:3000")
            .setClient(new OkClient()).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson));

    RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
```

Comment: which version of GSON are you using? And can you show me the POJO class

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html